# How to I write a recursive function for split even and odd indices of array?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, recursion

**This is question for my interview.**

Write a recursive function that does the following:

Input: An array A of length N. N is an even number and N >= 2.

Output: A reordered array B. The first half of B contains A’s elements with even indices. The second half of B contains A’s elements with odd indices. Convention: the first index of an array is 0 (and thus it is an even number).

```
Input 1: [4, 8, 12, 16]
```

For this array, the indices and the values are as follows:

```
Index: 0, 1,  2,  3
Value: 4, 8, 12, 16
```

Thus, the output is as follows:

```
Expected output 1: [4, 12, 8, 16]
```

ADDITIONAL TEST CASE

```
Input 2: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
Expected output 2: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

TASK

Write a recursive function in a programming language of your choice (as if you are writing real code to be used on a production server) for the above problem
In addition to the main function, you are free to write helper functions (if needed)

The code should have as few lines as possible (but it should still be clear and readable)

**Note: Your recursive function must show the 'spirit' of a recursive function (not just the recursive form of a for loop)**

**Here is my code:**

```
def slove(array, deep=0):
    '''para:
        array: list input.
    return: list.
    !!!Do not set value for deep!!!'''
    if len(array) > 2:
        if deep > 0:
            for i in xrange(0, len(array), 2):
                array[i], array[i + 1] = array[i + 1], array[i]
        left = array[0]
        right = array[-1]
        array = array[1:-1]
        array = slove(array, deep + 1)
        array.insert(0, left)
        array.append(right)
        return array
    else:
        array[0], array[-1] = array[-1], array[0]
        return array


if __name__ == '__main__':
    array = map(int, raw_input('Enter array with sep is space key: ').split(' '))
    # array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    print slove(array)
```

He said that it is wrong because I use loop in program. He is correct? So how to solve it?

Comment: If you're asked for a recursive solution and you're writing an iterative solution - it's the wrong solution. So to answer your first question: He is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use slicing?

```
lst = [11,12,13,14,15,16]
lst[0::2] + lst[1::2]
```

Returns:

```
[11, 13, 15, 12, 14, 16]
```

Comment: It like loop. The requirement is recursion algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

This pseudocode function might help:

```
Let A[n] and B[n] be the 2 arrays where n is the size.
```

Then we will call the following method `rearrange(0,0)`:

```
rearrange(int i, int j) {
    b[j] = a[i];
    b[j+n/2] = a[i+1];
    if (j < n/2-1)
        rearrange(i+2,j+1);
}
```

In this method, `i` jumps 2 times each therefore the odd items get stored in the first half of the output array. For the second half, `j+n/2` saves the even items.

Comment: Thanks, but Interviewer said: "Your recursive function must show the 'spirit' of a recursive function (not just the recursive form of a for loop)".

Comment: What is the 'spirit' of a recursive function?

Comment: I think it means 'concept of recursion'.

Answer (score 0):

This is one (awkward) way to do it:

```
def even_odd_split(seq):
    """
    >>> even_odd_split([4, 8, 12, 16])
    [4, 12, 8, 16]
    >>> even_odd_split([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
    [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
    """
    assert(len(seq) % 2 == 0)
    assert(len(seq) > 1)

    def _split(seq):
        if len(seq) == 0: return [], []

        a, b = _split(seq[2:])
        return [seq[0]] + a, [seq[1]] + b
    a, b = _split(seq)
    return a + b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: Is it true that your base case is if len(seq) == 0: return [], []. But why do you need to make the assumption that if len(seq)==0 because in the assert statement, we have assert(len(seq) > 1)?

Comment: Different functions.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it like this:

```
def f(l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        # only one element left
        return l
    if len(l) % 2 == 0:
        # length is even
        return l[:1] + f(l[1:])
    else:
        # length is odd
        return f(l[1:]) + l[:1]
```

Every invocation of the function removes one element from the list and either puts it at the beginning or at the end of the resulting list.

It does not produce the given “expected” outputs, because the elements of the list appear in another order than they appear in the input list, but it matches the specification… and also, I think it’s pretty simple.